# How to remove @Xsi.Type From Json Response

Tags: json, rest, cxf, jax-rs

My REST project JSONProvider is deserializing the response as follows:

```
{
   "Recipient":
   {
       "defaultAddresses":
       {
           "@xsi.type": "endPointAddress",
           "addr":
           {
               "@xsi.type": "emailRecipient",
               "emailAddress": "abc@xyz.com"
           },
           "type": "EMAIL"
       },
       "localeCode": "en_US",
       "preferredEncoding": "UTF-8",
   }
}
```

I want the "@xsi.type" attribute which is being set by JSONprovider to be removed. CXF documentation says that we need to set "writeXsiType" property to "false".
Can someone please give me any pointers about what can i do for this?